# How to get TCP client-server application to work across PCs

Tags: javascript, node.js

I want to know how two systems can communicate over **tcp**.
I have **node.js tcp *client and server*** codes. When tested on the same machine, the applications work well.
The problem is when I try to run the **server code** on one machine and the  **client code** on another machine, no connection is established.

The two PCs are running on Windows and are connected using switch. They can share resources.

Please any help to understand how this things work is highly appreciated.

**Here is the server code**

```
const tcpServer = net.createServer();

const PORT = 3030;
const HOSTNAME = '169.254.142.199';

tcpServer.on('listening', () => {
    console.log(`Server listening on port ${PORT}`, tcpServer.address());
})

tcpServer.on('connection', socket => {
    console.log(`Server connected to client on localport ${socket.localPort} and remotePort ${socket.remotePort}`);
    socket.on('error', err => {
        console.log(`error occured ${err.message}`);
    })

    socket.write('Hi Welcome');
});

tcpServer.once('close', () => {
    console.log('connection closed');
});

tcpServer.on('error', err => {
    console.log(`error occured ${err.message}`);
});

tcpServer.listen(PORT, HOSTNAME);
```

**Here is the client code**

```
const PORT = 3030;
const HOSTNAME = '169.254.142.199';

const tcpClient = net.createConnection(PORT, HOSTNAME, () => {
    console.log(`connected to server on port ${PORT}`, tcpClient.address());
});


tcpClient.on('error', err => {
    console.log(`error occured: ${err.message}`);
})

tcpClient.on('close', err => {
    console.log(`connection closed ${err ? 'with' : 'without'} error`);
})

tcpClient.on('data', data => {
    console.log('%s', data);
})
```

**169.254.142.199** is the IP address of the PC running the server code.

The error message is ***error occured: connect ECONNREFUSED 169.254.142.199:3030***

What am I doing wrong? Where am I missing it?
Thanks for your help.

Comment: Are there any firewall rules that might decline requests on port `3030`?

Comment: Don't know. How will I check?

Comment: Thanks @eol it has worked. I turn off Window firework to get it work.

Answer (score 0):

Finally it has worked.
I turned off Windows firewall and communication went through.
thanks to everyone.